# Terminal Condition for American Put Option

Tags: american-options

In a recent book I read, the author mentioned the terminal condition

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to T} V(S,t) = \max \left\{ {X - S,0} \right\}$$

This is intuitive to understand. Then he defines $$\tau  \equiv T - t$$ and when $r>0$, the terminal condition above can be simplified as

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\tau  \to 0} V(S,\tau) = 0$$

in the range $${\Sigma _1} = \left\{ {(S,\tau )|B(\tau ) \le S <  + \infty ,0 \le \tau  \le T} \right\}$$

This is not so intuitive . How can the value of the option be equal to zero in this case?

@Update: The book is " Homotopy Analysis Method
in Nonlinear Differential
Equations" p. 432

$B(\tau ) $= optimal exercise boundary

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. Can you provide the reference?

Comment: This makes no sense, it say the payoff is zero as the option approach maturity. Can you double check.

Comment: Could you also provide a reference?

Comment: Assuming $B(\tau)$ figures the **optimal exercice boundary** when the time to expiry is $\tau$ which is still not completely clear, i.e. $B(\tau)$ is such that:
$$B(\tau) = \text{argmax}_B \left\{ (X-B) \geq \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q} \left[ e^{-r\tau} (X-S_T)^+ \mid S_{T-\tau}=B \right] \right\} $$
then because $B(\tau) \to X$ in the limit as $\tau \to 0$, your put option is OTM in the range $\Sigma_1$ when $\tau \to 0$.

Comment: I think @Quantuple answers it. Basically, it means as your spot price is too high, the payoff is zero as it approaches to maturity.

Comment: @user10699 Could you please add the definition of $B(\tau)$ (or directly a scan of the reference book).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like r = S - X, or the strike price - stock price. Basically, if r > 0, the put is out of the money and becomes worthless as it goes to expiration.

Comment: But $S-X$ is not the same as $\max(S-X,0)$

Comment: If you're long the put, you can't lose more than the debit, thus V >= 0.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's just a guess of the question. We don't know from the question we're talking about OTM American.

Comment: The limit holds for both American and European-style options, in and out of the money.

As τ goes to zero, the values of American and Euro options converge, since they both can be exercised at expiration.

Comment: V(S,t) = S-X is only valid for an in or at-the-money option.

If max(S-X,0) = 0, the option _must_  be out of the money. Without the max(), a 100 put on a stock that closes at 105 would be worth -5.

Comment: I am with @StudentT on this. You cannot credibly answer the question without knowing the original reference. Everything else is just guessing what the notation might mean.